# OpenStack Networking Config

Tags: networking, virtualization, openstack

I'm setting up a single node/controller on a RackSpace VM (for testing) I have two interfaces the public one (31.222.162.*) and the local network one (10.177.68.*) but I dont know how to state the network config. Like the floating range, fixed range etc..

Im using the devstack script which uses these fields:

```
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=${PUBLIC_INTERFACE:-eth0}
FIXED_RANGE=${FIXED_RANGE:-10.0.0.0/24}
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=${FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE:-256}
FLOATING_RANGE=${FLOATING_RANGE:-172.24.4.1/28}
NET_MAN=${NET_MAN:-FlatDHCPManager}
EC2_DMZ_HOST=${EC2_DMZ_HOST:-$HOST_IP}
FLAT_NETWORK_BRIDGE=${FLAT_NETWORK_BRIDGE:-br100}
VLAN_INTERFACE=${VLAN_INTERFACE:-$PUBLIC_INTERFACE}
MULTI_HOST=${MULTI_HOST:-0}
```

Any ideas?